# JQuery popup windows on several elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, popup, orchardcms

I need to create popup for several element (projection) with different html code. I'm creatig webshop on ochard cms. I tried to use JQuery popup plugins for my task, but it can show popup only for the first element. How can I create different popup for different elements on one page?

P.S: So, I writed the module for Orchard CMS.

now I have div:

```
<div id="@Model.Name"> </div>
```

and button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alert('@Model.Name');" />
```

And it works. I tried several plugins (such as LightBox), but it doesn't works.

Comment: could you post an example on jsbin or jsfiddle? Are you using the same id for all your elements? Show us some code

Comment: "but it doesn't work" is not enough information. How does it not work? What does "it can show popup only for the first element" mean?

Comment: for example, I have page with 9 divs. I want 9 different popups, and each of them should contains html code of appropriate div. But when I try to write 1 script for every element, it'll work for only first div.